# Hyperledger fabric installtion issue - while trying to install npm

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, npm-install, node-gyp

Hello I am trying to setup the first application with HyperLedgerFabric

I am Following this [post](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/write_first_app.html#), I have set up the network properly everything seems perfect the issue is only with the npm install whenever I try to install npm using `npm install` or `sudo npm install` command
it show me below errors.

```
build error
stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
System Linux 4.8.0-53-generic
command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
cwd /home/dinesh/Documents/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/pkcs11js
node -v v8.11.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN fabcar@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
errno 1
npm ERR! pkcs11js@1.0.17 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
Exit status 1



Failed at the pkcs11js@1.0.17 install script.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

> gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/html/fabric-samples/fabcar/javascript/node_modules/pkcs11js/build'

Comment: Can you add a bit more to the error message you posted?  I think we might be missing some lines above what you posted?  FWIW, I just tried doing this with Node 8.11.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 with no issues

Comment: @GariSingh thanks for the response, I have node 8.11.0 and mint 18.2, but it show the error while try to install npm, I have added the main error in question

Comment: My guess is that somehow you were running as root or ran the command with sudo.
You don't need to be root or use sudo in general although I am not sure what the default permissions are for `/var/www/html`.  I'd advise cloning the fabric-samples in a directory owned by your current user ID and running `npm install` again as that user

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a problem on access node_modules folder. 
Just set full access for this folder.

> sudo a+rwx node_modules.

It works.